# date() format, differences between d-m-Y and d/m/Y

Tags: php, datetime

this is my first post so sorry if i do something wrong. Well I got this code

```
$min=date('d-m-Y');

$max=date ('31-12-2015');


function rand_date($min, $max) {


    $min_epoch = strtotime($min);
    $max_epoch = strtotime($max);

    $rand_epoch = rand($min_epoch, $max_epoch);

    return date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $rand_epoch);
}

echo rand_date($min, $max);//return 04-12-2015 07:48:22`
```

It works, but the problem comes when I use this with the format than i need (d/m/Y)

```
$min=date('d/m/Y');

$max=date ('31/12/2015');


function rand_date($min, $max) {


    $min_epoch = strtotime($min);
    $max_epoch = strtotime($max);

    $rand_epoch = rand($min_epoch, $max_epoch);

    return date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $rand_epoch);
}

echo rand_date($min, $max);// Always shows 01/01/1970 01:00:00`.
```

I need works with this format, so I will be grateful if somebody answer my question.

Comment: [Read, learn and inwardly digest](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) Date strings with a `/` are treated as US format `mm/dd/yyyy` by strtotime(), dates with a `-` are treated as European format `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: You may find that it's a lot easier to work with [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), and in particular the [createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method which allows you to identify the format that you're passing

Answer (score 3):

The default interpretation of `31/12/2015` for PHP date/time functions/methods is `m/d/Y` when using forward-slashes, and `d-m-Y` or `Y-m-d` when using dashes, if you [check the manual](http://php.net/datetime.formats.date). Which is why something like `date('31/12/2015')` returns `false` since there is no 31st month in a year.

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) instead to specify your own variations if you must.

### Example

```
$min = new DateTime;

$max = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/12/2015');


function rand_date(DateTime $min, DateTime $max) {
    $min_epoch = $min->getTimeStamp();
    $max_epoch = $max->getTimeStamp();

    $rand_epoch = rand($min_epoch, $max_epoch);

    return (new DateTime("@$rand_epoch"))->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: It's due to the behaviour of strtotime() method.  

echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11/12/10"));
// outputs 12th November, 2010

 
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11-12-10"));
// outputs 11th December, 2010  

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php