# facing issue in strtotime()

Tags: php, date

I am facing an issue in echo date() with some formats like:

if i use the format d/m/Y like: '18/04/2017' then date() does not recognize this because the format contain /

```
<?php
  echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime('16/04/2017'));
?>
```

> it will output: 01-01-1970

But when i use the format m/d/Y like: '04/18/2017' then date() it recognized

```
<?php
  echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime('04/16/2017'));
?>
```

> it will output: 16-04-2017

I am not getting these different behaviour of date(), can anybody help me please

Comment: see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825869/date-format-differences-between-d-m-y-and-d-m-y

Comment: Use strtotime(str_replace('/','-','04/16/2017')); . http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#100144

Comment: @blokeish i know this but, i want to know y this happening

Comment: Sorry about that. The link after explains that, which is same as what Mayank P posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date_create_from_format` to convert your date to any format you want. The problem with your code was that `strtotime` does not support this format.

[**Learn about strtotime formats**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

If you using `dd/mm/yyyy` then it will not work because does not comes under support format of strtotime. For using

**Supported formats:** (for `dd` `mm` `yyyy`)

> dd [.\t-] mm [.-] YY
>
> **Example:** 16-04-2017
>
> **Example:** 16.04.2017
>
> **Example:** 16\t04t\2017

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$date=date_create_from_format("d/m/Y","16/04/2017");
echo $date->format("d-m-Y");
```

Comment: yes it can be but what about my case

Comment: thanks to share the strtotime formats

Comment: @BunkerBoy Welcome .... :)

Answer (score 2):

> Forward slash (/) signifies American M/D/Y formatting, a dash (-)
>   signifies European D-M-Y and a period (.) signifies ISO Y.M.D.

So if your date is like `04/16/2017`, change the `/` to `-` and then use `date()` function on it to convert it to any format.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#100144)

[Working Code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a5fd6a75af64ff8d4f65e7e9bb7c85b6779cc5f)

Comment: Good to always give reference to your answer. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#100144. Use strtotime(str_replace('/','-','04/16/2017'))

Comment: @Mayank Pandeyz thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is replace `/` with `-` of given date

```
$date = '16/04/2017';
$date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($date));
```

Comment: thanks i know but i got my answer